# NFC (Android Studio) - How to enable/disabled NFC on a button click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

I have to do button, which will be enable/disable NFC on android. Before I do a button, which check if NFC is enabled. Now one button should enable and disable NFC.

My code (check button):

```
 button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nfc);
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
                NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NFC enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NFC disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: it is not possible to enable/disable NFC programmatically (AFAIK)

Comment: I can not do nfc enable on button click?

Comment: not on button click,, not on TextView click, not on the activity create. You just can't.

Answer (score 0):

hope this function will help you:

```
private void OnOffNFC() {
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your device not have NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

it will check first if your device have NFC hardware or not. if your device have NFC then it will take user to NFC setting else it will show simple toast that "Your device not have NFC"

Comment: Yea I know this, but how can I enable/disable NFC on button click?

Comment: You cannot enable/disable it yourself, the user has to do it as you won't have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />` permission .

Comment: @Andrew if i add the permission then i can enable or disable it ? any code example ?